# How Task scheduler works well?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I have a application which is written with c#. This app reads unread mails and download zips then send pdfs to printer. It works well when i  run app manually.

However, when i use task scheduler to run app with every 5 or 10 minites, application reads unreads mails download zips but it doesnt send pdfs to printer. why ? i use

> try catch

it doesnt give any error as well.

any logical idea ?

```
static void SendToPrinter(string path)
        {
     var printerName = "EPSON L310 Series";

                    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    info.Verb = "print";
                    info.FileName = path;
                    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    info.Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\"";

                    Process p = new Process();

                    p.StartInfo = info;
                    p.Start();
       }
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ8tm.png)

Comment: Have you tried configuring the scheduled task to run under your account?

Comment: İ added image @Sean my operating system is win 10

Comment: Check the credentials, after some amount of time the account user is changing to `SYSTEM` that his privileges are restricted. if that is the case, `impersonation` can be a solution, also consider writing a `windows service` that will always run in the background with your own timer instead of task scheduler.

Comment: Can u explain credentials please how  can i do  @jonathana

Comment: Check the user, for example: `Environment.UserName` will output the current username account. also, you can read here about  `impersonation`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @jonathana i used windows service however it is same. It downloads files but it doesnt send to printer like task scheduler :/